# Cassandra insert data into table column with data type set<text>

Tags: cassandra, cql

We're trying to setup an INSERT statement on a table with a set<text> column data type in Cassandra, but have come up with no luck.  Here's an example:

```
INSERT INTO test_table
    (my_items)
VALUES
    ([{"test1":"test val 1","test2":"test val 2"}])
```

The result is always something like:

```
no viable alternative at input for [test val ]2
```

Comment: Show your table schema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Enclosing values in curly brackets and separate by comma**

Example :

Let's we have the schema :

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id text PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name text,
  last_name text,
  emails set<text>
);
```

Insert :

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id, first_name, last_name, emails)
    VALUES('frodo', 'Frodo', 'Baggins', {'f@baggins.com', 'baggins@gmail.com'});
```

Update :

```
UPDATE users SET emails = emails + {'fb@friendsofmordor.org'} 
     WHERE user_id = 'frodo';
```

More [Using the set type](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_set_t.html)

---

**Edited**

If you want to insert value `"test1":"test val 1"` and `"test2":"test val 2"` into set then **enclose each value with single quote**

Example :

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id, first_name, last_name, emails)
    VALUES('2011331035', 'Md Ashraful', 'Islam', {'"test1":"test val 1"', '"test2":"test val 2"'});
```

Comment: What if with the set<text> column I wanted to use key/value pairs for the data though, like the example in the question?  I think that's where the issue is.

Comment: @what3vo why don't you use map ?